Text inside autocompletion suggestion gets visual selection appearance
I'm having this visual bug where after I accept an autocomplete suggestion the text inside the function gets the visual selection appearance and it doesn't dissappear until I change from one buffer to another or enter normal mode and make a new line.
Visual bug example
This also happens when using autocomplete in Rust:

I would like to know if someone else has had this behaviour and know what it's the problem. Thanks in advance!
I'm using NVIM v0.10.3 and reduced my neovim configuration to installing lazy.nvim and feeding this lsp.lua configuration:
return {

        {
        'saghen/blink.cmp',
        dependencies = 'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets',

        version = 'v0.*',
        opts = {
                appearance = {
                        use_nvim_cmp_as_default = true,
                        nerd_font_variant = 'mono'
                },

                sources = {
                        default = { 'lsp', 'path', 'snippets', 'buffer' },
                },
        },
        },

        {

        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        dependencies = {
                "williamboman/mason.nvim",
                "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
        },
        config = function()
                local capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend(
                        "force",
                        {},
                        vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities(),
                        require('blink.cmp').get_lsp_capabilities())
                require("mason").setup()
                require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
                        ensure_installed = { "rust_analyzer", "gopls"},
                        handlers = {
                                function(server_name)
                                        require("lspconfig")[server_name].setup {
                                                capabilities = capabilities
                                        }
                                end,
                        }
                })
        end
        }
}



Welcome. Note that this site is not a substitute for issue trackers. You should try and narrow the problem down to one of your plugins and report it there.

Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for reducing your config—you might check out How to debug my vimrc to see if you can narrow down to a particular plugin or combination of plugins that triggers the problem. (You might also look at :verbose autocmd, mappings, and similar scripting hooks to see if anything jumps out.)
